# How to add service in consul - using groovy jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a question about how to add service in Consul by Jenkins groovy pipeline. Find only how to add KV

Comment: Hey Maksim can you be a bit more explanatory? From your question I guess you want to add a service to Jenkins via a console? What is a KV? please explain a little more and you for sure will get an answer

Comment: I have installed Consul and want register services in Consul by Jenkins with groovy pipepline